# exclude a class from the_content in wordpress in a template page

Tags: wordpress, function

I've a output template ( from some product research), using `the_content()` of a page.
I'd like to exclude one class from `the_content()` (which is from a page using Default template).

I've seen it was possible using a function, but how to realize it? I've only found to exclude shortcode which I'm not looking to do . . .

thank you in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  When you say "exclude one class", are you referring to an HTML element with a specific class name?

Comment: exactly =) it's an html element in css class which id like to hide =)

Comment: Why not just hide it with CSS?  Set the selector to `display:none`.

Comment: Or drop in a jQuery one liner: `jQuery('.yourClassName').remove();`  You could also use `.hide()` in place of `.remove()`.  Writing a function to look inside of `the_content()` for some HTML/string and then strip it seems like overkill.

Comment: I tried by doing this, but doenst work :s , I can not use any css for this ar it will affect other pages :s

`<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            the_content(jQuery('.page-title').remove(););
            wp_reset_query();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    MetaDataFilter::mdf_shortcode_quick_js_injection();
    ?>`

Comment: You misunderstood how to include the jQuery snippet.  I'll post an answer below with some instructions.  You cannot put jQuery inside the parenthesis on `the_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your `header.php` file.  Right before the closing `</head>` tag you'll want to include the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // change .yourClassName to the actual class you want to remove.
        jQuery('.yourClassName').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could use a conditional PHP statement wrapped around some CSS inside the `<head></head>` tags to hide it. Again, you would do this in the `header.php` file.  Using the conditional statement you could tell the CSS to only work on a specific page and not affect any other pages.  See below.

```
<?php if (is_page(1)) { ?> 
    <style type="text/css">
        /* change .yourClassName to the actual class you want to hide. */
        .yourClassName {display:none;}
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```

If you go the CSS route, you would set the page ID of the page you want the CSS to affect by changing the number 1 inside of `is_page(1)` to the appropriate page ID.  You could also use the page slug, so in place of the number 1 you could use `'your-page-slug'`.  You can read up on the `is_page()` function [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page).

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: awesome ! I did by the is_page and worked perfectly ! thank you so much :)

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to do the same is_pge trick but for page translated via WPML ?

I've a couple of css class / div who are not well align, ( on the same page)

Thank you :)

Comment: You're very welcome, glad I could help.  Unfortunately I do not know much about WPML.  I did find this with a quick Google search though: http://wpml.org/forums/topic/is_pagex-how-to-point-to-a-page-and-its-tranlations/  Maybe that will help get you headed in the right direction.